# Value of a Cookie with cURL or similar

Tags: c, windows, cookies, curl, cmd

I have learned how to call o PHP file/page on the server from the command line (cUrl). A more secure way of establishing what I want to do, would be the ability to read the value of a previously set cookie. I'd like to it either with C or more preferably with the windows dos-like command line.

The most convenient way would be:

```
C:\cURL get_value_of_cookie "mycookie"
```

and the value of the cookie would be presented in the stdout stream.

that `get_value_of_cookie` is what I do not know how to do.

the cookie has been set by the PHP script:

```
setcookie("mycookie","A_CERTAIN_VALUE");
```

Rgds

Kari

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the curl option `--cookie-jar` (especially with value `-`) and `--junk-session-cookies`. To *send* data as a cookie, use `--cookie`.

```
curl --output /tmp/website.html --cookie-jar /tmp/website.cookies.txt http://www.example.egg
```

For completeness, the analogous options in `wget` are `--save-cookies`, `--load-cookies` and `--keep-session-cookies`.

Comment: Thanks, It seems to do something, but I might have some security or other issues. I found no documentation on this --cookie-jar selector. What does this /tmp/website.html refer to? /tmp/website/cookies.txt seems to be the oputput file and www.example.egg the site "owning" the cookie. OR?

Comment: `--output` specifies the file into which the website itself is saved; `--cookie-jar` specifies the file into which the cookies are saved (and loaded from for subsequent calls). You can use the special filename `-` to write to the standard output (your screen) instead. Say `man curl` (even in Google if you aren't sitting at a terminal) for the full documentation.